# bot evitar mayusculas

Tags: python, discord.py

Eestoy intentando crear un bot para que evite las mayúsculas pero no consigo hacerlo, aquí dejo mi código en Python:

Si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='') #ive tried both true/false. neither works 

print("Starting...")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged on as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith(message.content.upper()):
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))

bot.run("")
```

Comment: Utiliza el método `.is_upper()` para saber si un texto está en mayúsculas

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora el problema esque cuando escribo un numero o dos puntos : me salta el bot

Comment: De que forma?? Te genera un error o te lo toma como mayúsculas??

Comment: Si, me lo toma como mayusculas: aqui dejo la imagen https://i.imgur.com/7WykDpz.png

Comment: primero tendrías que verificar que sea una cadena alfabética o alfa-numérica luego verificas si está en mayúsculas. Por cierto no pongas un snippet, eso solo sirve para código JS, HTML y css, voy a quitarlo